# Can we declare a datatype from a string in java

Tags: java

Assume i have a String called samplestring

```
String samplestring="int";
```

can i declare a variable called "samplenumber" with type int like this

```
samplestring samplenumber;
```

instead of

```
int samplenumber;
```

Comment: Short anwer: no. Longer answer: You would need to use a reflection to do that. But only with an instance of Integer class, not with primitive type.

Comment: No..The compiler has to understand the type/details of all your variables before compiling..

Comment: Short answer: No. Long answer: Nooooo.

Comment: Why do you need this? Can't generics fulfill your requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cast an Object with reflection like this:

```
String datatype = "java.lang.Integer";
Object integer = 42;
Object castedInteger = null;

try {
    Class intClass = Class.forName(datatype);
    castedInteger = intClass.cast(integer);

    System.out.println(integer.getClass() + " " + castedInteger.getClass());
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But honestly: Why would you need this? The output will be:

*class java.lang.Integer class java.lang.Integer*